# Add css to replaceWith element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, replace, replacewith

I simply want all the input to be replaced with h1 tag and, text to turn red when I click a button.

Why doesn't this work?

```
 $('#container').find('input').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith('<h1>'+ this.value + '</h1>').css(
    'color', 'red'
  );
});
```

I need it to be added via jQuery because I plan to select from a random color each click, but I cant even get this to work.

Comment: Well that's not *all* you want; you also seem to want to replace the `input` with a `h1`.

Comment: `$('input').addClass('css-class-with-error');` would do what you've asked, then define a CSS class: `.css-class-with-error{ color: red; }`

Comment: Read the docs: "it must be noted that the original jQuery object is returned. This object refers to the element that has been removed from the DOM, not the new element that has replaced it."

Answer (score 1):

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/c3kuz8p7/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="input1"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input2"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input3"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input4"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="input5"/>
<br/>
<button class="submit">Click me</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function () {
        $('input').css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

Please explain what else you need.

Comment: Sorry, I also wanted to replace with a h1 tag then turn it red.

Answer (score 1):

After a little research and messing around this worked:

```
$('#container').find('input').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<h1 />").text(this.value).css(
    'color', 'red'));
 });
```

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NCHJB/401/)**

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is instead of replacing it with a string that contains html, replace it with a jquery object representation of your code with the css added.

```
$('#container').find('input').each(function() 
{
    $(this).replaceWith( $('<h1>'+ this.value + '</h1>').css('color', 'red') );
});
```